# Is there any way to get the diff tool to report only the relative path of files in a recursive diff?

Tags: command-line, diff

I'm trying to get a unified diff between many pairs of directories so I can ensure the comparison between pairs is consistent, and I want to know if there's a way to get `diff` to format the output with relative rather than absolute paths.

Right now if I use `diff -r -u PATH1 PATH2` then I get this kind of output:

```
diff -r -u PATH1/some/subfile.txt PATH2/some/subfile.txt
--- PATH1/some/subfile.txt     Tue Feb 07 09:16:31 2017
+++ PATH2/some/subfile.txt     Tue Feb 07 09:16:32 2017
@@ -70,7 +70,7 @@
  *
  * some stuff
  *
- * I am Tweedledee and you are not
+ * I am Tweedledum and you are not
  */
 void twiddle(void)
 {
@@ -88,7 +88,7 @@
  * check whether we should destroy everything
  * and then destroy everything in either case
  */
-inline static void Tweedledee(void)
+inline static void Tweedledum(void)
 {
     if (should_destroy_everything())
     {
```

I would rather get just the relative paths... is there any way to get `diff` to do this? example:

```
diff -r -u PATH1/some/subfile.txt PATH2/some/subfile.txt
--- some/subfile.txt
+++ some/subfile.txt
@@ -70,7 +70,7 @@
  *
  * some stuff
  *
- * I am Tweedledee and you are not
+ * I am Tweedledum and you are not
  */
 void twiddle(void)
 {
@@ -88,7 +88,7 @@
  * check whether we should destroy everything
  * and then destroy everything in either case
  */
-inline static void Tweedledee(void)
+inline static void Tweedledum(void)
 {
     if (should_destroy_everything())
     {
```

This would make it easier to compare diff reports which are expected to be the same. (in my case `PATH1` and `PATH2` differ in each case, whereas the relative paths to files, and the exact content differences are the same)

Otherwise I have to filter this information out (either manually or with a script)

Answer (score 1):

I would pipe the output of your diff command to a sed script something like this:
    $ diff -r -u PATH1/some/subfile.txt PATH2/some/subfile.txt | sed '1s/PATH1\///' | sed '2s/PATH2\///'
The script says": on line 1, replace "PATH1", followed by a single forward slash, by nothing, then, on line 2, replace "PATH2", followed by a single forward slash, by nothing. I'd have to create some content to test it, so I haven't tested it.

Comment: You could even get fancier:
sed '1s/^\\(--- \\)PATH1\//\1/'
and
sed '2s/^\\(+++ \\)PATH2\/\1/'
These two statements just say only to remove PATH1 and PATH at the beginning of the line when preceded by '--- ' and '+++ ' respectively.

Comment: thanks... bah, I just parsed it in a Python script to do what I wanted.

Answer (score 0):

I bit the bullet and did this parsing in Python; it removes the `diff blah blah blah` statements and relativizes the paths to a pair of specified root directories, also removing timestamps:

```
udiff_re = re.compile(r'^@@ -(\d+),(\d+) \+(\d+),(\d+) @@$')
diffitem_re = re.compile(r'^(\+\+\+|---) (.*)\s+.{7} \d\d \d\d:\d\d:\d\d \d{4}$')
def process_diff_output(output, dir1, dir2):
    state = 0
    lines_pending = [0,0]
    result = []
    for line in output.splitlines():
        if state == 0:
            if line.startswith('@@'):
                m = udiff_re.search(line)
                if m:
                    nums = [int(n) for n in m.groups()]
                else:
                    raise ValueError('Huh?\n' + line)
                result.append(line)
                lines_pending = [nums[1],nums[3]]
                state = 1
            elif line.startswith('--- ') or line.startswith('+++ '):
                m = diffitem_re.search(line)
                whichone = m.group(1)
                filename = m.group(2)
                dirx = dir1 if whichone == '---' else dir2
                result.append('%s %s' % (whichone, os.path.relpath(filename, dirx)))
            elif line.startswith('diff '):
                pass  # leave the diff cmd out
            else:
                raise ValueError('unknown header line\n'+line)
        elif state == 1:
            result.append(line)
            if line.startswith('+'):
                lines_pending[1] -= 1
            elif line.startswith('-'):
                lines_pending[0] -= 1
            else:
                lines_pending[0] -= 1
                lines_pending[1] -= 1
            if lines_pending == [0,0]:
                state = 0
    return '\n'.join(result)
```